# open two Drawer layout on right side

Tags: android, drawable

I want to open two drawer layout in right side.

I can not close both layout on right side.

My code is for xml file is :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_job"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Editext for Search -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backbuttonfromsearchscreen"
                android:layout_width="35dip"
                android:layout_height="35dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Results"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/layoutLiearAsc"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                android:background="@drawable/up"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/layoutLiearRefine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="1sp"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:text="Refine"
                android:textColor="#3399FF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/com.example.PolicyImplimentation.Font_arial2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
            android:background="@drawable/textline"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_jobsearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- List View -->


    <!-- Right Drawrer -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/whatYouWantInRightDrawer"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/backbuttonfromsearchscreen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="27dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/backarrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Refine"
                        android:textSize="20dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/layoutColon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="27dip"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:text="Done"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/RefineResult"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0 results" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/com.example.PolicyImplimentation.Font_arial2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textline"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/rightJobDrawer"
                    android:layout_width="280dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:divider="#666666"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/layoutReset"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="27dip"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:text="Reset"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/layoutset"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- you can have many more widgets here like buttons or labels -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/whatYouWantInRightDrawerLocation"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/backbuttonfromsearchscreen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="27dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/backarrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Refine"
                        android:textSize="20dip"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/layoutColon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="27dip"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:text="Done"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/RefineResult"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0 results" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/com.example.PolicyImplimentation.Font_arial2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textline"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/rightJobDrawer"
                    android:layout_width="280dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:divider="#666666"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="27dip"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:text="Reset"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/layoutset"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- you can have many more widgets here like buttons or labels -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My code to close both layout is:

mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(whatYouWantInRightDrawer);

mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(whatYouWantInRightDrawerLocation);

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplifies your view to make easier to read:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Firstly when open roght dwaer, i have one button on first right drawer, On click of button i will open second right dwaer on same page, How to do this,Help me

Comment: Then use the OpenDrawer() function.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to open two drawer on the same side but one on swipe and another on click right??

So do the following:

1. **Write your Swipe right navigation drawer, which is the the one that opens the drawer when you swipe from right**

   2. **After that use the button to open the second drawer also lock it so that it won't open on swipe** i.e

You can lock the drawer with the following code

```
drawer.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD);
```

For the buttons to open the second drawer

```
Button button =(Button) findviewById(R.id.theid);
```

and set the on click listener i.e.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener());
```

Hope it helps